# p-confirm dialog is always scrolled to the bottom when content overflows

Tags: html, css, angular, types, primeng

I am using primeng confirm dialog in my application. When the content is more than the max height of the dialog, the dialog becomes scrollabel. However the content is always scrolled to the bottom & the user has to scroll up. This is not convenient for the user. I want to know how can I make the scroll start from the top instead of the bottom. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Here is my template code:

```
<p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation"  [style]="{'overflow-y': 'auto', 'overflow-x': 'hidden',
'max-height': '60vh','min-height':'150px'}" icon="pi pi-exclamation-triangle">
</p-confirmDialog>
```

My ts code:

```
this.confirmationService.confirm({       
          message: 'some big msg',
          header: 'Confirm',
          icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',

          accept: () => {
            console.log('Confirm');
          },
          reject: () => {
            console.log('Reject');
          }
       });
```

Comment: Try to set `[defaultFocus]="'none'"` on the confirmDialog

Comment: I get this error Can't bind to 'defaultFocus' since it isn't a known property of 'p-confirmDialog'.Removed the [ ] & then the error goes away. But the issue is still there

Comment: ahh, i'm sorry. I'm not familiar with primeNg, you have to pass it as a parameter to the `confirm` call: `confirm({ defaultFocus: 'none', // ... })`

Comment: I tried that too. I get this error- Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'defaultFocus' does not exist in type 'Confirmation'

Comment: I guess you are not using version 9 of primeng, that's where this option was introduced. Soo, I'm out of ideas now :)

Comment: yeah. I'm using 7. I guess I'll have to create a custom dialog then.

Comment: that sounds a bit excessive. You can also create a custom directive, or some dirty code to scroll to top on dialog show

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue, but I do not see it happening. My guess is that something in your application is doing the scrolling: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-7-1-2-dnxukh

Comment: Oh. I can also see that in your example, the yes button is in focus when launched while in mine the no button is in focus

Comment: is that `no` button part of your body? If so, you should not have it focus on it :)

Comment: Also unlike your example, my buttons disappear if I scroll up whereas your's are fixed

Comment: you should check what style rule is causing this

Comment: Also I see that you didn't set any style rules for the scroll. For me I have to explicitly set overflow for the scroll to appear

Comment: I believe you didnt add any primeng theme, is that correct?

Comment: I'm using a custom theme.

Comment: then i guess that custom theme is missing some essential stylings :)